# Using utilityProcess in Electron vite template

Tags: electron, vite

Newbie to Electron and Vite here. I'm betting this is a simple question that I'm missing obvious on.

I'm trying to run a background process through using a [utilityProcess](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/utility-process). The first parameter in the fork method is the file path to the utility script.

Here's my file structure:

```
src
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── preload.js
├── renderer.js
├── test.js (utility process file)
```

Here's my `main.js` file content:

```js
const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  if (MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL);
  } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, `../renderer/${MAIN_WINDOW_VITE_NAME}/index.html`));
  }

  const { port1, port2 } = new MessageChannelMain()
  const child = utilityProcess.fork(path.join(__dirname, 'test.js'))
  child.postMessage({ message: 'test' }, [port1])

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};
```

I know the issue is me using `path.join(__dirname, 'test.js')` since this works if I use Electron without webpack or Vite. I'm trying to figure out to resolve the `test.js` file correctly through Vite so I can execute that file. I gave [explicit URL imports](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports) a shot to with no luck.